# Is there a reliable way to determine in the minibuffer from which buffer the interactive command was invoked?

Tags: buffers, minibuffer

Simply checking the buffer-list is not enough, because an interactive command can be invoked via various ways, not just directly or via M-x. E.g. if you invoke it via a Helm-like selector package which creates various buffers for selection then the buffer list is affected.

Is there a reliable way to determine the origin buffer of a command which uses the minibuffer for input?

Comment: Doesn't most (or all) of the time the function `current-buffer` provide it?

Comment: @dalanicolai when you are in the minibuffer then the minibuffer is the current buffer, not the invoking buffer

Comment: Ah okay. Well I've tested it in Spacemacs (using `ivy`) calling the following command:
`(defun test (dir)  (interactive "D")  (print (current-buffer)))`,
it printed the buffer from where I invoked `ivy-switch-buffer`, instead of the minibuffer. I remember something that `helm` does not use the minibuffer, which could be relevent (or not)... (I can not get the code block formatted 'correctly' here in the comments)

Comment: Your print function runs after the minibuffer was invoked. You can try the same using `minibuffer-setup-hook` which is called when the cursor is in the minibuffer.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Well, than the answer on my 'original' comment is probably NO :)

Comment: Maybe you could use the workaround to set a `pre-command-minibuffer` variable to the current buffer via the `pre-command-hook`, unless the current-buffer is a minibuffer. Maybe you'd have to exclude some other (types of) buffers, but otherwise this might work

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to know what buffer that is, in general.

---

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can know: it's the value of variable `icicle-pre-minibuffer-buffer`:

> Buffer that was current before the minibuffer became active.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? I believe the answer is correct: *Emacs provides no way to know which buffer was current when the minibuffer was activated.* (And yes, if in `icicle-mode` minor mode then you can know what that buffer is.)

Comment: When the action running in the minibuffer is finished and it is not an action which switches to another buffer (like `other-window`), I suppose it should come back to the origin buffer. So, I guess that something somewhere should know how to reach this buffer... Maybe it's too hidden in the calling stack or in C code?